# How can I get my 10g ports to work on my Qhora q301w?

Tags: openwrt

I just flashed My 10g ports seem to be permanently DOWN, I can't even set them UP manually when they're plugged in,

```
ip link set 10g-2 up
```

Immediately after `ip link` still shows down. This is what dmesg says about the 10g ports,

> ```
> aquantia_phy_api_ops_init[2241]:INFO:qca probe aquantia phy driver > succeeded!
> Aquantia AQR113C 90000.mdio-1:08: aqr107_wait_reset_complete failed: -110
> Aquantia AQR113C 90000.mdio-1:08: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=90000.mdio-1:08, irq=POLL)
> Aquantia AQR113C 90000.mdio-1:00: aqr107_wait_reset_complete failed: -110
> Aquantia AQR113C 90000.mdio-1:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=90000.mdio-1:00, irq=POLL)
> ```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice in [this commit message](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt/openwrt.git;a=commit;h=bd17683261e1dde1fdd4223745852de1ce8cfc89), but with some modifications, namely I used the blob [here](https://github.com/0x5826/QNAP-QHora-301w-Guide/releases/tag/AQR_ethphyfw_5.6.7), as it was newer.

- Grab the ethphy firmware image from: https://github.com/0x5826/QNAP-QHora-301w-Guide/releases/tag/AQR_ethphyfw_5.6.7
- Move it over to the router,

  - On your device with the firmware, run

    ```
    cat AQR_ethphyfw_5.6.7 | nc -l -p 5050
    ```
  - On the router run

    ```
    nc $yourmachine 5050 > AQR_ethphyfw_5.6.7
    ```
  - Validate shas are the same with `sha1sum`
- Run `grep -i "0:ETHPHYFW" /proc/mtd`, confirm you get mtd10.
- Optionally, Backup the 0:ETHPHYFW partition,

  ```bash
  dd if=/dev/mtd10 of=/tmp/ethphyfw.backup
  ```

  - Run `nc -l -p 5050 > /tmp/ethphyfw.backup` on $yourmachine
  - and, then run `cat /tmp/ethphyfw.backup | nc $yourmachine 5050` on the router.
- Over a serial cable, in Uboot, write the new firmware image to the 0:ETHPHYFW partition

  ```
  mtd erase /dev/mtd10
  mtd -n write AQR_ethphyfw_5.6.7 /dev/mtd10
  fw_setenv bootcmd "aq_load_fw 0; aq_load_fw 8; bootipq"
  saveenv
  reset
  ```